# Can I reference a theme, that resides in one database, in another database?

Tags: themes, xpages

I was just looking into referencing css files in a theme, that reside in a different database and I was wondering:

Could I reference a whole theme that resides in a different database as well with "extend"?

The reason behind that is: Would it possible to keep themes in one central database that can be used by all kinds of applications and therefore, if there should ever be changes to the themes, they only have to be changed in one location and not in every application.

Thank you for your responses in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no I don't think this is possible (happy to be wrong if someone else knows it is?)

to keep all your theme files in a central spot, an XspLibrary in an OSGi plugin is a good solution, however it is a steep learning curve if you haven't done this before. The benefit is once you know this technique it opens the door for 'centralizing' other parts of xpages.
you deploy the plugin to each server and each client if using xpinc, and the every nsf can use a theme from that plugin.

there are a few 'getting started with xpages plugins' articles popping up around. check through planetlotus.org (I'll edit this answer later with some links)

once you know how to do an XspLibrary, you can then download the source code of the bootstrap4xpages project on OpenNTF to see how they are serving up their theme from a plugin.
it relies on the Extension library though so if you don't use the exit lib you could reverse engineer the necessary parts of that project too!
this bootstrap project was set up by Phillipe Riand who was the chief architect of XPages, so it should be a good example!

I am halfway through creating a video series on doing a theme from a plugin but have temporarily lost motivation :(. I might finish it sometime this year, if I do I will post a link to it on this answer. in the meantime I am happy to answer any questions you have about it if you want to give it a go.

otherwise, a quick and dirty solution would be put the theme files / CSS / images directly on the file system of the domino server, where the other theme files are. 'Mastering XPages' might have some advice about this but I don't have it with me right now :)

Comment: Hello Cameron, thank you for your response. I figured it wouldn't be possible. The idea with the OSGi plugin sounds intriguing. However, I am currently wrapping my mind around Bootstrap and also trying to get into the Java development side of XPages, so, I fear my head will explode should I also try and get into OSGi plugins. So, I think I will stick with just keeping the .css, .js files in one location and create the theme for each application, referencing the locally kept files.

Comment: OSGi plugin is a definite possibility. That will be how OneUI v3 is done and also the new mobile theme. So the Extension Library may be another point of reference. It's probably a good idea to put the files on the server for now, building confidence on the format you want. Then maybe come back to it in a few months, when you've built up your Java skills and build it into a plugin at that time.

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer is you won't be able to load just a theme from a different database.

Each NSF has it's own JVM, sitting on top of the server JVM. So you can extend a theme that's sitting on the server, but not one in another NSF.

XPages Single Copy Design loads a theme from a different NSF by effectively loading the template's JVM. So it's the theme, but also all other design elements.

Jesse Gallagher's done some work in OpenNTF Domino API to allow you to load an XPage or Custom Control from another database, but I'm not sure if that would work for a theme.

If you want to design once and use in many, you can add the theme to the server itself. Looks for the OneUI elements to see where you need to store it (or it may be mentioned in Mastering XPages). You can only nest themes to five levels, but you should be fine.

Comment: Hello Paul, thank you for your response. I figured it wouldn't be possible. Putting the theme on the server directly is something that came to my mind as well, though I think it would be a more elegant solution to have the theme in a database and make changes to it there, if necessary, and don't have to worry getting a hold of your admin in order to update the theme (and possibly .css, .js and images) on the server.